# Production branch matches origin, yet there's divergence?

Tags: git

I know that production/master is completely sync'd with origin/master (using `git log`). Yet, when I do `git status` on production server, I get:

```
git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 184 commits.
```

Why is it saying ahead by 184 commits? While both branches match 100%?

Comment: You did `git fetch origin` on `production`, right?

Comment: Your local Git repo is comparing your local `master` against the local tracking branch, and it thinks you are way ahead.  In reality, you may be behind.  By the way, `origin/master` is _not_ the `master` branch on the remote repository, it is a local branch whose job is to track the remote as closely as possible.

Comment: No, I did `git pull origin master`. I always do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `git status` says that "your branch is ahead of 'origin/master'" you can list the extra commits by doing

```
git log origin/master..master
```

If you are certain those commits are on `origin`, you can fetch them

```
git fetch origin
```

If they are not on `origin`, you can put them there

```
git push origin master
```

If you are still confused, perhaps the output of this `git log` might help:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --color
```

It will show a graph of all commits and annotate them with the branch name.